# Define a function, its range set is a union of two other function range sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've been asked to give a specific definition of a computable function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, so that Its range set $W_f = W_h \cup W_g$. Whereby $W_h $ and $W_g$ are range sets of the functions $h : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ and $g :  \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ respectively, which are computable functions.

---

I know that the definition of the function $f$ has to be dependent on the other functions $h$ and $g$. I was thinking about giving a piecewise funcion
$$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            h(x) & \quad x \ is \ even  \\
            g(x) & \quad x \ is \ odd
        \end{array}
    \right. $$ But i don't think that's the answer because the function $h$ domain may contain odd numbers, which have an image in $W_h$ and not contained in $W_f$.

Further, i don't know how to deal with elements that have an image in g as well in h (i.e $h(x) \neq g(x)$ for the same x)

I need some help! 
Please note that i am new here, so if i did something wrong let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function should work:
$f(x) = h(\frac{x}{2})$ where $x$ is even and $f(x) = g(\frac{x+1}{2})$ where $x$ is even. This gives every possible input of $h$ and $g$ and so satisfies the conditions given.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.